# I'm sending out two http requests instead of one in Angular when I request data from the server for the state to change

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, observable

I'm building a beginner application in Angular and I'm at the point where I'm getting some data back from a server and I've built the pagination for the data I recieve. Each click on a button (at the bottom for the pages) routes to a specific page and then it requests the data from the endpoint (I extract the id from my local url and give it to the endpoint url (myUrl + exctratctedParam (id) = endpoint)).

The problem is that whenever I click on a page button I need to click it twice for the data to show. The data is coming through, the first and the second time but only the second time it changes the state of the component, the first time the state is the same as it was at the beginning of the component.

Code

-people-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-people-list',
  templateUrl: './people-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./people-list.component.css'],
})
export class PeopleListComponent implements OnInit {
  peopleList?: any = [];
  url = 'https://swapi.dev/api/people';
  pageNums: number = 0;
  currentPage = '1';
  arrayOfPages?: any;

  constructor(
    public dataService: DataService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCharacters();
  }

  getCharacters(): void {
    const page = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')!;
    this.currentPage = page;
    this.dataService
      .getData(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=${page}`)
      .subscribe((characters: any) => {
        this.peopleList = characters.results;
        this.pageNums = Math.floor(characters.count / 10 + 1);

        console.log(characters);

        this.arrayOfPages = Array(this.pageNums)
          .fill(0)
          .map((x, i) => i + 1);
      });
  }
}
```

-dataService.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { tap, catchError, of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { MessagesService } from './messages.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
  error?: string;
  data?: any = [];
  numOfPages = 0;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private messageService: MessagesService
  ) {}



  private errorHandling<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(error);

      this.messageService.add(`${operation} failed.`);

      return of(result as T);
    };
  }

  getData(url: string) {
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(
      tap((msg) => this.messageService.add('Data loaded.')),
      catchError(this.errorHandling('getData', []))
    );
  }
```

HTML people-list.component

```html
<h2>STAR WARS CHARACTERS</h2>
<div>
  <div *ngIf="peopleList.length === 0">Loading characters...</div>
  <ul *ngIf="peopleList">
    <li *ngFor="let person of peopleList">
      <app-person-detail [person]="person" [personId]="person.url" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <button (click)="getCharacters()" routerLink="/people-list/{{page}}" *ngFor="let page of arrayOfPages">{{page}}</button>
  </div>
  <button routerLink="">Home</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the html template where you are rendering the fetched data?

Comment: could you try injecting `private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef` and marking the component for check in subscribe `.subsccribe(() => {... this.cdRef.markForCheck();})` and see if it works

Comment: @gastonchatelet I edited the post with the HTML code for rendering the data.

Comment: @Andrei I tried it, but it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will always render:

```
<ul *ngIf="peopleList">
    <li *ngFor="let person of peopleList">
      <app-person-detail [person]="person" [personId]="person.url" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Because `peopleList` is initialized as an empty array. You could change the ngIf condition to

```
<ul *ngIf="peopleList?.length > 0">
    <li *ngFor="let person of peopleList">
        <app-person-detail [person]="person" [personId]="person.url" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

or inyect a changeDetectoRef:

```
constructor(
    private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef,
) {}

getCharacters(): void {
    const page = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')!;
    this.currentPage = page;
    this.dataService
      .getData(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=${page}`)
      .subscribe((characters: any) => {
        this.peopleList = characters.results;
        this.cdref.detectChanges(); 
        //... rest of the code
```

Comment: The problem was actually when I was defining the page in the getCharacters() method. I was setting the currentPage as the page which I was on when making a request, so that's why there was a double request. I made it work now, but thanks for the input :).